# How do you make the browser automatically change to the route to the destination?

Tags: node.js, express

I am very desperate for help. I've been on this problem for a couple of days now and have found no answer. I am currently new with Node.js and I think I'm missing a key aspect but not sure what it is. I have followed a few tutorials building Node.js projects but they are often just one paged html only. I'm trying to expand to multiple pages. 
(I'll try to provide as much as information as I can.)

I am currently trying to build a web page that has a form(index.html) that asks users for information. When the user hit submit it sends a post request to the database and sends a 200 status back when successful. Then the browser should go to another page(makeMatches.html).

Here is my problem: 
I want the page to go from 'localhost:3000' to 'localhost:3000/createEvent' after hitting submit but the browser does not do that, it stays at the same page at 'localhost:3000'. But, if I manually type 'localhost:3000/createEvent' it is able to load the html file. So I need help getting my web page to get point A to point B automatically.

I have done other variations of the code that included express.router() and express.engine() but they didn't really solve my problem.

Here is how my directory is built like:
**project:**

**--index.js**

**--dbqueries.js**

**--views(folder)**

**---- index.html** 

**---- makeMatches.html** 

**---- style.css** 

**---- app.js**

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const dbqueries = require('./dbqueries')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
})

app.get('/CreateEvent', function(req, res){
  console.log('get /createevent')
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/makeMatches.html')
})

app.post('/CreateEvent', function(req,res){
  //if emtpy return error
  if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  //else send event info to db
  console.log('creating event...')
  dbqueries.createEvent({
    time: req.body.time,
    date: req.body.date,
    location: req.body.location,
    message: req.body.message,
    singles: req.body.singles,
    couples: req.body.couples
  })
  .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
})

//start server
app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('Server running on port 3000'))
```

**app.js**

```
const createEvent = document.querySelector('.CreateEvent')
createEvent.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  console.log('starting in app.js')
  e.preventDefault()
  const time = createEvent.querySelector('.time').value
  const date = createEvent.querySelector('.date').value
  const location = createEvent.querySelector('.location').value
  const message = createEvent.querySelector('.message').value
  const singles = createEvent.querySelector('.singlesValue').value
  const couples = createEvent.querySelector('.couplesValue').value
  console.log(time, date, location, message, singles, couples)
  post('/CreateEvent', {time, date, location, message, singles, couples})
})

function post(path, data){
  return window.fetch(path, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
}
```

When I inspect the page and hit the submit button I see an item called CreateEvent and when I hover over it it says 'localhost:3000/CreateEvent' but the type is fetch.

Comment: can you post the ' index.html' code also?

Comment: have you tried `window.location.href = '/CreateEvent;` after form is successfully submitted?

Comment: on your app.post, for the form submit, you do some nifty things but you dont return your   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/makeMatches.html')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.js

```
 const createEvent = document.querySelector('.CreateEvent')
 createEvent.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

 e.preventDefault()
 const time = createEvent.querySelector('.time').value
 const date = createEvent.querySelector('.date').value
 const location = createEvent.querySelector('.location').value
 const message = createEvent.querySelector('.message').value
 const singles = createEvent.querySelector('.singlesValue').value
 const couples = createEvent.querySelector('.couplesValue').value
 post('/CreateEvent', {time, date, location, message, singles, couples}).then(()=>{
   window.location.href = '/CreateEvent'; // you were missing redirection on success
 })
})

function post(path, data){
 return window.fetch(path, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! this has solved my problem! I think I was thinking too much that express was the answer that I didn't even think about the client side.